# an infinite loop using ngDoCheck()

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-changedetection

While playing around with the `NgDoCheck()` I got an infinite loop, and I have no idea how or why. If I run this, and check the browser console, I see the `ngDocheck()` keeps on being called. I only have 1 component, the template is just a form with 3 inputs (on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wdb4jy)). Can anybody help?

```js
export class AppComponent {

  testvar: number=0;
  product: Product= new Product();
  productOne: Product = new Product();
  productTwo: Product = new Product();

  constructor(){
    this.productOne.name="productOne";
    this.productOne.category="soccer";
    this.productOne.price=5.5;
    this.productTwo.name="productTwo";
    this.productTwo.category="basketball";
    this.productTwo.price=8.6;
  }

  submitForm(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.valid) {
      // this.model.saveProduct(this.product);
      this.product = new Product();
      form.reset();
    }
  }

  ngDoCheck(){
    console.log("I am called");
    this.product=new Product();
     let startvar = this.testvar;
     if(this.testvar==0){
       Object.assign(this.product, this.productOne  );
     }
    if(this.testvar==1){
       Object.assign(this.product, this.productTwo );
      this.testvar=0;
    }
   if(!(startvar==1&&this.testvar==0)){
    this.testvar++;
   }

  }
```

Comment: `ngDoCheck` is used to determine if the component should be checked for changes. You trigger a ChangeDetection cycle inside this hook by changing variables that are bound to the template. This leads to the framework calling `ngDoCheck` again and repeats at infinitum. Did you mistake `ngDoCheck` for `ngOnInit` or `ngOnChanges`?

Comment: Thank you, you solved my question. the problem is that I change this.product, which is bound to the template. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

*ngDoCheck* performs additional change detection checks apart from the default change detection. To make it simple, when a component renders by default a change detection cycle takes place in which *ngOnInit* will be sufficient enough. But, lets say you have value coming into your component from a parent component after the component has rendered, then you will have to detect that change using *ngOnChanges*. Futhermore, if you need to detect additional changes apart from the default checks from Angular (for example: a change from a directive) then you will have to use *ngDoCheck*.

But, *ngDoCheck* is really expensive as you will have so many changes in the component even if you dont realize it, which may include clicks on the input fields or changes made by angular from anywhere in the component during the initial component load. So even before you start typing on the input fields you will have hundreds of ngDoChecks performed. This can reduce the performance of your application drastically. It isn't recommended unless you need it.